# Completely update matplotlib figure (not appending data)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Edit: I got it to work by omitting matplotlib animation completely and adding `plt.ion()` before initializing the figures.

I have a measurement device that sends data to my PC that I can read with Python. Every second it sends 100 data points. Every time these 100 points are received, they can be obtained by calling a function. I want to update the figure, starting from X=0 again. The data contains X and Y data.
In other SO threads I found that `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` can update the graph efficiently, but I have only found examples where data is appended to the graph.
At the moment, my graph is redrawing, but it just draws new points without clearing the previous graph and it is really slow (I can't drag the plot window while it's drawing). The clear function just leaves me with a grey window.
Does anyone know a fast enough workaround for this problem? Thanks a lot!

My current implementation:

```
def plot():
    freq = np.linspace(f_start, f_stop, points, endpoint=True)

    def update(frame):
        #for i in range (iterations - 1):
        print(frame)
        complex_data = vna.data(0)
        plotFigure(figInitProperties, freq, Rect2Pol(complex_data))
        time.sleep(2) # Wait for all points to be scanned

    ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figInitProperties[2], func=update, frames=(10), repeat=False)
    plt.show()
plot()
```

`figInitProperties` returns the `fig` (size, labels, axis, ticks etc.) of the figure.

Comment: Please show the code for your current implementation

Comment: You mean like in [this maptlotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/animation/strip_chart.html)?

Comment: @Mr.T No, this one is appending values to the plot, not refreshing the image with full different XY data

Comment: I suggest providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.clear()` or `plt.cla()` at the beginning of the update function.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is leaving me with an unresponsive grey window.

Comment: Those commands clear the current axes. If you do that in the function where you plot the new data, it should work. Probably your `plotFigure` function?